# Drag versus centripetal force

Tags: drag, centripetal-force

I'm trying to see how extensive a gaming engine's physics are.

Consider a spinning disc with a box on it which is free to spin around a vertical pole connecting it to the disc. The pole is more towards one end of the box.

How would this box align itself as the disc spins? Would it be tangential to the disc? Or would the end of the box farthest from the pivot be thrown outwards, like the rear of a car going too fast around a corner which has lost rear wheel grip?

Or is this a battle between the centripetal force not going through the center of gravity of the box, and air resistance, and thus dependent on disc speed and the box's mass?

[image]

Comment: Does the joint have any friction? Or is the only _dissipative_ force drag?

Comment: Both drag and centripetal force are proportional to $v^2$, so it depends on the coefficients ($\frac12\rho C_dA$ for drag and $m/r$ for the force).

Comment: Good point ja72. Let's say no friction on the joint.

Comment: do not forget the Coriolis force

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is drag, the final position will always be: at rest with the center of mass pointing away from the center, although slightly skewed from directly pointing away. To see this, notice that, in a reference frame rotating with the disk,  there are four forces acting on the block's center of mass: Centrifugal, internal tension, [Coriolis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_effect) and drag. The centrifugal is always radially out the disk and the tension in relative to the pivot, so we can imagine that the box is a pendulum where we replace centrifugal by gravity. Thus it is a pendulum with two additional forces that depend on speed. The drag, opposite to the speed, can in turn be decomposed into two forces: one that does not depend on relative speed and is proportional to $(R\omega)^2$, and another one that will depend on the relative speed relative to the pivot, will act as friction and dissipate energy. The Coriolis force will act always radially relative to the pendulum's center (either away or in) , and so will change speed direction but not speed magnitude (will not increase the pendulum's kinetic energy). Thus the initial "potential" (from the centrifugal force) energy of the pendulum will be dissipated by the relative drag and reach an equilibrium position at rest (relative to the rotating disk). This position will be with the center of mass at the "bottom", that is, radially out but skewed in a tangential direction opposite to the angular speed. The equilibrium being at the direction of the "effective" gravity: the combination of "external" forces that do not depend on speed relative to the pivot: the centrifugal force and the component of the drag that is proportional to proportional to $(R\omega)^2$.

Note: The velocity of the drag force can be split into two components, one rotating with the disk and the other relative to the disk (that is, relative to the pivot):  $v=R\omega+v_{pivot}$, so the total drag force, is proportional to $(R\omega)^2+v_{pivot}^2+2R\omega v_{pivot}$. The first term introduces a tangential force, and the other two a dissipation force. The non-dissipative term points always negative relative to the pivot, so an eventual equilibrium position must be reached.

Comment: True _except_ aerodynamic forces do not go thought the center of mass, but through the [center of pressure](https://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Center_of_pressure.html) and thus inducing a rotation. So the final position will be slightly skewed from directly pointing away.

Comment: You are correct that there is always drag, I forgot that while I was writing the answer, I'll update the answer, thanks!

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat yes, I agreed that I forgot the largest component of the drag, but it cannot pump energy to the system beyond skewing the position. Let me think how to show this easily (assuming I am correct, which I am not 100% sure)

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat I added a note clarifying this, let me know if you find any problems. Thanks!